# Copy form object and adding new fields

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have two versions of the same form, one with "username" field and one without, and I am choosing one of them in runtime based on configuration option.
[Please have a look here](https://github.com/tabdulradi/securesocial/blob/7448d35c28d874d6b295cb1590d69045d7012acf/module-code/app/securesocial/controllers/registration/FullRegistration.scala#L52-85)
I wish if I can write this instead:

```
val formWithUsername = formWithoutUsername ++ Form[FullRegistrationInfo](mapping(UserName -> nonEmptyText))
```

Is there something similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, but try to make the `UserName` field mapping optional so it doesn't get in your way when you don't need it:

```scala
mapping(
  UserName -> optional(nonEmptyText.verifying(Messages(UserNameAlreadyTaken), userName => {
    UserService.find(IdentityId(userName, providerId)).isEmpty
  })),
  ...
)
```

Since the case class corresponding field already is optional, there won't be any harm.

Still, the `Password` mapping isn't the same for the two forms. So you should keep them all, refactoring the similar parts.